# Django Rest Framework: validate HiddenField CurrentUserDefault property

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am using DRF to create an API in a single page application.
I have a customer user class to which I have only added a *is_manager* flag and a *managerEntity* model where users that have the *is_manager* flag as True can create managerEntities becoming owners of them.
The problem is that I can't seem to figure out how to validate the data from the serializer before create method to check whether the *is_manager* is set or not. If set, the *managerEntity* should be created, if not, raise an exception.

```
class DeepmetricsUser(AbstractUser):
    is_manager = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class managerEntity(models.Model):
    id              = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name            = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    owner           = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    team            = models.ManyToManyField(get_user_model(), blank=True)
```

views.py

```
class managersEntityViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = managerEntity.objects.all()
    serializer_class = managerEntityModelSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.queryset.filter(Q(owner = self.request.user) | Q(team=self.request.user.id))


    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = managerEntitySerializer(data=request.data, context={"request": self.request})
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        res = serializer.save()
        data = managerEntityModelSerializer(res).data
        return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

serializer.py

```
class managerEntitySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    name    = serializers.CharField(max_length=255)
    owner   = serializers.HiddenField(default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault())
        
    def create(self, data):
        res = managerEntity.objects.create(**data)
        return res
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override the `validate` method in Serializer

```
def validate(self, attrs):
   if not self.context["request"].user.is_manager:
      raise serializers.ValidationError("Validation error")
   return attrs
```

Comment: Thanks! This works as intended in spite of getting the user object from the request which I believe is the same as getting it from serializers.CurrentUserDefault()
EDIT: is exactly the same thing:
`class CurrentUserDefault:
    requires_context = True

    def __call__(self, serializer_field):
        return serializer_field.context['request'].user`

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that fits better my needs by using permissions. The answer provided by Shakeel is correct as I asked for validation and that should be done as he suggested but, what I really wanted to do was checking for enough clearance for the user to manipulate a resource, then, permissions is what's best fits:

```
class createManagerEntity(BasePermission):
message = "Not enough privilegies"
def has_permission(self, request, view):
    return request.user.is_manager
```